# ld: library not found for -lpq when build rust in macOS

Tags: rust, linker-errors

When I build my rust project in macOS with apple sillicon using this command:

```
CARGO_HTTP_MULTIPLEXING=false cargo build
```

shows error like this:

```
  = note: ld: library not found for -lpq
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried to install

```
brew install libpq
brew link --force libpq
```

still did not fix this problem, what should I do to fix this problem? Is it the PostgreSQL lib did not support Apple Sillicon(Apple M1 Pro) right now? This is my project dependencies:

```
[package]
name = "reddwarf_dict"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
# database
diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
chrono = "0.4"
log = "0.4"
env_logger = "0.9.0"
config = "0.11"
rust_wheel = "0.1.0"
```

Comment: Could you fix it?

Comment: yes, I could fix this issue by follow these answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Firstly, I run these commands:

```
brew install libpq
brew link --force libpq
```

Then:

```
PQ_LIB_DIR="$(brew --prefix libpq)/lib"

cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

It works for me.

macOS: Big Sur 11.5

Answer (score 18):

I solved it with:

```
cargo clean
```

later

```
cargo build
```

Comment: Surprisingly this worked for me xD

Comment: It worked by 
1. `brew install libpq`
2. `brew link --force libpq`
3. `cargo clean`
4. `cargo build` or `cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres` 

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I'm using Diesel ORM in my project here: https://github.com/EstebanBorai/estebanborai.com and this is how I set up
the project to support Diesel.

1. Install `libpq` using Homebrew

```sh
brew install libpq && brew link --force libpq
```

2. Then add the library to your PATH

```sh
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

3. Finally install Diesel CLI

```sh
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

#### Cargo.toml

This is my `Cargo.toml` file for reference on versions:

```
# -- snip --

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["chrono", "postgres", "r2d2", "uuidv07"] }
r2d2 = "0.8.9"

# -- snip --
```

#### Diesel CLI

This is the output for my Diesel CLI version

```sh
< diesel --version
> diesel 1.4.1
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems paths got moved in BigSur and/or Monterrey. I solved it by explicitly specifying the library path.

IE running rustc in the CLI:

```
rustc -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib ./main.rs
```

You can also specify it in the RUSTFLAGS env var, IE:

```
export RUSTFLAGS='-L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib'
```

And then run:

```
rustc ./main.rs
```

or:

```
cargo build
```

In your example, you could do:

```
CARGO_HTTP_MULTIPLEXING=false RUSTFLAGS='-L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib'
 cargo build
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem for this error message when running my cargo build:

```
= note: ld: library not found for -lpq
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The way I solved it was by installing the required postgres C libraries using `brew`

```
brew install libpq
brew link --force libpq
```

Optionally if you are using `fish` like I was I also added a link like this:
`fish_add_path /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin`