# rust diesel linking with `cc` failed

Tags: rust, linker, rust-diesel, cc

Ok, so kind of getting nowhere here. Before I posted a problem with my Mac M1 having linker issues with Rust Diesel and got nothing. So I spun up an Ec2 instance and tried to run this crate here and got the following:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
...
 = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
```

I've installed the following:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install git -y
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
sudo yum install cmake -y
sudo yum install postgresql-libs -y
```

Seriously, how are people managing to get this crate running?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Diesel [Getting Started](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started) guide:

> If you run into an error like:
>
> ```
> note: ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```
>
> This means you are missing the client library needed for a database backend – `mysqlclient` in this case. You can resolve this issue by either installing the library (using the usual way to do this depending on your operating system) or by excluding the undesired default library with the `--no-default-features` flag.
>
> By default diesel depends on the following client libraries:
>
> - [`libpq`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq.html) for the PostgreSQL backend
> - [`libmysqlclient`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-implementations.html) for the Mysql backend
> - [`libsqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) for the SQlite backend
>
> If you are not sure on how to install those dependencies please consult the documentation of the corresponding dependency or your distribution package manager.
>
> For example, if you only have PostgreSQL installed, you can use this to install `diesel_cli` with only PostgreSQL:
>
> ```
> cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
> ```

The error "`cannot find -lpq`" is your linker telling you that it cannot find the PostgreSQL client library.

Comment: I couldn't install ```libpq``` on the EC2 but I did install ```postgresql-libs``` and I'm getting the same error. I also have these drivers on my mac but it results in ```dyld: Symbol not found: _PQconnectdb``` I have done postgres dev with python in the past, this diesel crate seems to be the most brittle thing I've ever worked with

Comment: @max89 Do the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70313347/2189130) help you out?

Answer (score 4):

The issue was caused by a missing library.
For Linux

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

For Windows,
Check the version of rust you have installed

```
rustup --version
```

then copy the libq.lib from

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\lib
```

to

```
C:\Users\"Your User"\.rustup\toolchains\"Your version of Rust-Nightly or Stable"\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib
```

Worked for me !!

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Fedora 36. The problem seemed to be that there were 2 versions of Postgres in my PC, and diesel couldn't figure out which library to use. So here's what solved it:

```
sudo dnf remove postgresql10-libs
sudo dnf install postgresql14-libs
sudo dnf install postgresql14-devel
```

Edit: this worked for a bit, but then broke again. I fixed it with:

```
sudo dnf remove postgresql14-devel
sudo dnf install libpq-devel.x86_64
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32197301)