# ld: library not found for -lpq when build rust in macOS Monterey

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am trying to use [diesel](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started.html) with postgres. I have managed to install it but when I try to run it, it does not compile.

The error message:
  `= note: ld: library not found for -lpq clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I have already tried the solutions presented here: [ld: library not found for -lpq when build rust in macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313347/ld-library-not-found-for-lpq-when-build-rust-in-macos).

I have also done `brew install libpq` and set the environment variable `PQ_LIB_DIR="$(brew --prefix libpq)/lib"`

My machine is using the Apple M1.

my main file:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use diesel::query_dsl::RunQueryDsl;
use diesel_orm::{
    establish_connection,
    models::{Event, User},
    schema::{events::dsl::events, users::dsl::users},
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let connection = establish_connection();
    let event_results = events.load::<Event>(&connection)?;
    let user_results = users.load::<User>(&connection)?;

    println!("Displaying {} events", event_results.len());
    for event in event_results {
        println!("{}", event.name);
    }
    println!("Displaying {} users", user_results.len());
    for user in user_results {
        println!("{}", user.user_name);
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

my lib file:

```rust
#![warn(clippy::pedantic)]
#![allow(clippy::must_use_candidate)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
use crate::models::{Event, NewEvent, NewUser, User};
use crate::schema::{events::dsl::events, users::dsl::users};
use anyhow::Result;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::query_dsl::RunQueryDsl;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env::var;

pub mod models;
pub mod schema;

/// # Panics
/// Function panics is the database connection fails
pub fn establish_connection() -> PgConnection {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("Error connecting to {database_url}"))
}

pub fn create_event(conn: &PgConnection, name: &str) -> Event {
    use schema::events;

    let new_event = NewEvent {
        name,
        ..Default::default()
    };

    diesel::insert_into(events::table)
        .values(&new_event)
        .get_result(conn)
        .expect("Error inserting new event")
}

pub fn create_user<'a>(conn: &PgConnection, user_name: &'a str, password: &'a str) -> User {
    use schema::users;

    let new_user = NewUser {
        user_name,
        password,
        liked_event_ids: &[],
        disliked_event_ids: &[],
    };

    diesel::insert_into(users::table)
        .values(&new_user)
        .get_result(conn)
        .expect("Error inserting new user")
}

/// Gets all events in database
///
/// # Errors
///
/// Returns [`Err`] if it is unable to retrieve `Event`s
pub fn get_events(conn: &PgConnection) -> Result<Vec<Event>> {
    Ok(events.load::<Event>(conn)?)
}

/// Gets all users in database
///
/// # Errors
///
/// Returns [`Err`] if it is unable to retrieve `User`s
pub fn get_users(conn: &PgConnection) -> Result<Vec<User>> {
    Ok(users.load::<User>(conn)?)
}
```

My schema file:

```rust
table! {
    events (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        name -> Text,
        uri -> Nullable<Text>,
        startdate -> Nullable<Text>,
        enddate -> Nullable<Text>,
        category -> Nullable<Text>,
        info -> Nullable<Text>,
        bookurl -> Nullable<Text>,
        price -> Nullable<Text>,
        location -> Nullable<Text>,
        source -> Nullable<Text>,
    }
}

table! {
    users (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        user_name -> Text,
        password -> Text,
        liked_event_ids -> Nullable<Array<Int4>>,
        disliked_event_ids -> Nullable<Array<Int4>>,
    }
}

allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
    events,
    users,
);
```

```rust
use super::schema::{events, users};
use diesel::Queryable;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Queryable, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i32,
    pub user_name: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub likes: Option<Vec<i32>>,
    pub dislikes: Option<Vec<i32>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Queryable, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Event {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub uri: Option<String>,
    pub start_date: Option<String>,
    pub end_date: Option<String>,
    pub category: Option<String>,
    pub info: Option<String>,
    pub book_url: Option<String>,
    pub price: Option<String>,
    pub location: Option<String>,
    pub source: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Insertable)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct NewUser<'a> {
    pub user_name: &'a str,
    pub password: &'a str,
    pub liked_event_ids: &'a [i32],
    pub disliked_event_ids: &'a [i32],
}

#[derive(Default, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "events"]
pub struct NewEvent<'a> {
    pub name: &'a str,
    pub uri: Option<&'a str>,
    pub startdate: Option<&'a str>,
    pub enddate: Option<&'a str>,
    pub category: Option<&'a str>,
    pub info: Option<&'a str>,
    pub bookurl: Option<&'a str>,
    pub price: Option<&'a str>,
    pub location: Option<&'a str>,
    pub source: Option<&'a str>,
}
```

my cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "diesel_orm"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.4", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
anyhow = "1.0.13"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any further tips on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Problem trying to install diesel (Mac air m1)](/q/70383711/2189130) Or perhaps this: [cannot link libpq on Mac M1](/q/70637566/2189130)

Comment: No neither of them worked sadly

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Posgres installed as well as `libpq`. As I've also [answered on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76594626/12559), this worked for me:

```bash
brew install libpq postgresql@15
brew link postgresql@15
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres,sqlite
```